# How can I convert 32bit to 16bit image with expression?

Tags: python, tcl, expression, 16-bit, nuke

I'm working in Nuke with `32bit` float image. I would like to apply math expression (can be TCL or Python) to convert values to `16bit` half float.

Any ideas what math formula can I use?

Can anyone please help with equation to "compress" `32 bit float` to `16 bit half float`?

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

Unlike ***Blackmagic Fusion*** or ***Apple Shake***, there's no magical **knob** in ***The Foundry NUKE*** allowing you to change file's bit depth.

[image]

If you wanna change a bit depth of an input image, you have to render your sequence using a new bit depth value for `datatype` property in **Write** node.

Here's how your code should look like:

```
import nuke

write = nuke.nodes.Write(file='/Users/nuker/file.%03d.exr', file_type='exr')
write['datatype'].setValue('16')
```

P.S.

Not all file types support `16-bit half-float` depth. But **OpenEXR** does support it. And I have to mention that all color grading and color correction operations **in NUKE are performed in 32-bit float space**, even if your files are 8-bit or 16-bit.